# Regex get all content between brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello i've this string  `["type",[129,167,85,83]]` that i want to extract only : 
`[129,167,85,83]` using regexpr

I tried with the following :

```
var re = new RegExp('",(.*)]');
var r  = '["type",[129,167,85,83]]'.match(re);
if (r)
    console.log(r);
```

But this gives me the following result : 
`",[129,167,85,83]]`
please how could i fix that ?

Comment: Sounds like a situation better suited for `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

the trick was that adding `(?<=,)` will execlude comma.

Added a test below, see for your self

```js
var regex = /(?<=,)(\[.*?\])/g;
var json = '["type",[129,167,85,83]]';
var r  = json.match(regex);

console.log(r);
```

Comment: Lookbehind is not supported in all browser.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily the best solution, but the quickest from where you are now.  `Match` produces an array - you want the second item:

```js
var re = new RegExp('",(.*)]');
var r  = '["type",[129,167,85,83]]'.match(re);
if (r) console.log(r[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON.parse

```js
let str='["type",[129,167,85,83]]';
let arr=JSON.parse(str);
arr.shift();
let new_str=JSON.stringify(arr.flat());
console.log(new_str);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `.split()` characters followed by `[` and closing `]`, get element at index `1`

```js
let str = `["type",[129,167,85,83]]`;
let [,match] = str.split(/.(?=\[)|\]$/);

console.log(match);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to use JSON.parse.
I have made a little example for you below;

```js
var course = '["type",[129,167,85,83]]';
var resultArray = JSON.parse(course);
console.log(resultArray[1]); // 129,167,85,83
```

Answer (score 0):

try this
`var re = new RegExp('(?<=",)(.*)(?=])')`

Comment: Lookbehind is not supported in all browser.

Comment: @Toto My browser is chrome ,its version is 71.0.3578.98